# Files under build folder are generated and should not be edited (How Resolve)

Tags: android

[Here is the error in values-v24 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/282aB.jpg)

Hi  I have an error Files under build folder are generated and should not be edited Can anybody tell me how to resolve this problem

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/green_100</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>



<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143025/discussion-on-question-by-muhammad-adeel-manzoor-files-under-build-folder-are-ge).

Answer (score -1):

@Muhameed could you try closing the Android studio deleting the build folder and then restarting the Studio

Comment: Which compileSdkVersion you are using?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23

Comment: please post your build.gradle

Comment: Which android support library's version you are using?

Comment: from where i see this version??

Comment: under the dependencies in build.gradle file

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

Comment: could you post your complete dependencies where you have added firebase compile dependencies

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'

Comment: could you change the complieSdkVersion to 25

Comment: when i do this it gives an error, (sync failed, basic functionalities not working like editing and debugging)

Comment: so what should I do next?